# How do I capture stylus event in Honeycomb?

Tags: android

I've been trying to capture MotionEvents that are from the stylus and I want to filter out those events that non-stylus. However, every event that comes in is a pointer event SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN (4098). How can catch the ones I want which are SOURCE_STYLUS (16386)? API 14 ICS is nice that I can check for the event's tool type but it's not available to me in Honeycomb API 11-13.

Thx,
-mL

Comment: If you are referring to an active stylus, that will be manufacturer-dependent AFAIK.

Comment: Well I have a ThinkPad Tablet.

Comment: Then you would have to ask Lenovo. They hopefully have a developer Web site with instructions for how to interpret their stylus events.

Comment: I had no intentions of inking that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To distinguish whether a MotionEvent is derived from a human thumb or a TPT’s pen, Volker polls MotionEvent.getTouchMajor(). If a fatty finger touches the screen, the diameter of the ellipse will be > 0. If it’s an anorexic digitizer pen, it will be 0.0f.](http://knowledge.lapasa.net/?p=490)